# SQL ORDER BY using a value in another table using an equation grouped by duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have been given a movie database and I am trying to order by user rating held in a separate table to my movie information. 
My problem is that my database does NOT have an overall rating of a movie, but only singular user ratings attached to that movie. But I want to order it by the overall average rating
For example:

```
SELECT Movies.title, Movies.movie_id, Movies.poster, Ratings.rating 
FROM Movies INNER JOIN Ratings 
ON Movies.movie_id = Ratings.movie_id 
WHERE genre LIKE '%action%' AND (origin = 'american') 
ORDER BY Ratings.rating DESC;
```

*(Rating is only selected to showcase to you the values, I do not need to use them outside this query)
This works out to display

```
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+
| title                   | movie_id | poster                             | rating |
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+
| The Baytown Outlaws     |        2 | posters/The Baytown Outlaws.jpg    |      5 |
| A Dark Truth            |        8 | posters/A Dark Truth.jpg           |      4 |
| A Dark Truth            |        8 | posters/A Dark Truth.jpg           |      3 |
| American Made           |       14 | posters/American Made.jpg          |      3 |
| Avengers: Age of Ultron |        4 | posters/Avengers Age of Ultron.jpg |      3 |
| Romeo Must Die          |        1 | posters/Romeo Must Die.jpg         |      3 |
| Avengers: Age of Ultron |        4 | posters/Avengers Age of Ultron.jpg |      2 |
| Fast & Furious 6        |        3 | posters/Fast & Furious 6.jpg       |      2 |
| Olympus Has Fallen      |        9 | posters/Olympus Has Fallen.jpg     |      1 |
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+--------+
```

Now from this I want to have my query select groups based on movie title, add up the ratings of that group, average that value, and then order titles by that average and excluding duplicate title names from the return
So my ideal query would return:

```
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+
| title                   | movie_id | poster                             |
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+
| The Baytown Outlaws     |        2 | posters/The Baytown Outlaws.jpg    |
| A Dark Truth            |        8 | posters/A Dark Truth.jpg           |
| American Made           |       14 | posters/American Made.jpg          |
| Romeo Must Die          |        1 | posters/Romeo Must Die.jpg         |
| Avengers: Age of Ultron |        4 | posters/Avengers Age of Ultron.jpg |
| Fast & Furious 6        |        3 | posters/Fast & Furious 6.jpg       |
| Olympus Has Fallen      |        9 | posters/Olympus Has Fallen.jpg     |
+-------------------------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

So this returns my movie info ordered by average rating then excluding duplicate titles

Baytown Outlaws has 1 rating at 5 -> overall 5

Dark Truth has 2 ratings at 4 and 3 -> overall rating of 3.5 but only displays one row of movie info

American Made has 1 rating at 3 -> overall 3

etc.

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out this exact query, or if it is even possible. Any help or keyword suggestion would be useful as I am somewhat new to SQL and don't know all of its strengths. If not possible, I would also appreciate an answer saying so, so that I can go ahead and rework the database system to instead follow a better system of saving the overall rating within the Movies table.

Comment: If getting a *derived* table of the `[MOVIE_ID, AVG(RATING)]`, where MOVIE_ID is the *group* to the average rating aggregate (and this is a trivial query), it can be simply joined with the reference tables to get a query with the names. This is because the name/release info are functional dependencies of the ID.

Comment: So the query would look something like: `SELECT .. FROM Movies m JOIN (SELECT .. FROM Movies .. /* derived query creating computing the average rating-per-movie */) m_avg on m.movie_id = m_avg.movie_id .. ORDER BY m_avg.rating DESC`; see the documentation for aggregates and `GROUP BY` to flush such out - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html (AVG, in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(rating)` group by `movie_id` (or title).
Something like this:

```
SELECT Movies.title, Movies.movie_id, Movies.poster, SUM(Ratings.rating)/COUNT(*) AS avg_rating 
FROM Movies INNER JOIN Ratings 
ON Movies.movie_id = Ratings.movie_id 
WHERE genre LIKE '%action%' AND (origin = 'american') 
GROUP BY Movies.movie_id ORDER BY avg_rating DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, as a beginner to SQL it amazes me how much it can do. I'll have to really look into how useful this `AS` operator can be as it was never taught in my class for this

Comment: The `AS` is just assigning an alias to the whole mathematical operator so it can be used in the `ORDER BY` in this case. Actually without assigning `SUM(Ratings.rating)/COUNT(*) AS avg_rating`, you can still use `ORDER BY` as such `ORDER BY SUM(Ratings.rating)/COUNT(*) DESC` .. but with an alias, it is much easier to look at and understand. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the AVG function and a group by on multiple columns.

The tricky part of using AVG in that case is that when using such a function, every element in the SELECT part must either be in the GROUP or be an aggregate function. That being said, If you make groups by a combination of ID and Movie title, you would obtain the same result (in this case) as if you grouped by ID only.

You can use that to your advantage to add these columns in your SELECT section while using the AVG aggregate function.

In your first table, every time you look at the **A Dark Truth** movie, it comes with the same id, 8. Every time you look at the value **Avengers: Age of Ultron**, it comes with the same id, 4.

I suggest taking a few minutes and drawing a Venn diagram of the problem to get a good grasp of it as it seems this is material of a class.

I [made a fiddle to demonstrate it for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1370bb/2). You can play around with it and add your initial join and where to complete it, I did a slight variation of the initial model, the create table is also in the fiddle.

```
SELECT Movie_id, Title, Poster, AVG(Rating)
FROM MoviesRatings
GROUP BY Movie_id, Title, Poster
ORDER BY AVG(Rating) DESC
```